# A CASE is returning the value of 0.85 instead of the actual row value

Tags: sql-server, case

I have three tables:

Step_Atts
ToolCode_Company1
ToolCode_Company2

I am trying to pull the field "efficiency" from both tables that match to Step_Atts. When I do this, it provides me with only one response (0.85) when in reality, the efficiency ranges from 0.7 to 0.9 depending on the Tool Code Name.

```
SELECT
    Step_Atts.UDF_ToolCode,
    CASE
        WHEN (SELECT ToolCode FROM Company1.dbo.JT_ToolCode WHERE ToolCode = Step_Atts.UDF_ToolCode) IS NULL
            THEN (SELECT TOP (1) UDF_EFFICIENCY FROM Company1.dbo.JT_ToolCode WHERE ToolCode = Step_Atts.UDF_TOOLCODE)
        ELSE
            (SELECT TOP (1) UDF_EFFICIENCY FROM Company2.dbo.JT_ToolCode)
        END AS "Efficiency"
FROM Company1.dbo.[Step_Atts], Company1.dbo.JT_ToolCode, Company2.dbo.JT_ToolCode
WHERE
    Step_Atts.UDF_ToolCode = JT_ToolCode
```

I attempted to do two exists in the Where, but the system times out when doing this.

I am unsure what I have done incorrectly to get Efficiency to only return 1 value for all rows rather than return the value for "Efficiency" that corresponds to the appropriate row in Company1 or Company2.

With comments from @SeanLange, I have attempted to modify the query:

```
      With Tools AS (
    Select
        COALESCE(t1.ToolCode, t2.ToolCode) as ToolCode,
        COALESCE(t1.UDF_Efficiency, t2.UDF_Efficiency) as UDF_Efficiency
    from COMPANY2.dbo.JT_ToolCode t1
        full outer join
        COMPANY1.dbo.JT_ToolCode t2
            on t1.ToolCode = t2.ToolCode
    )


SELECT 
      sa.UDF_ToolCode
      ,t.UDF_EFFICIENCY as Efficiency
      ,[JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_INPUT].[UDF_DATE]
      ,[JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_INPUT].[UDF_QUANTITY]
      ,[JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_INPUT].[UDF_PROGRAM]
      ,[JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_PROGRAM_SCHED].[UDF_SEQUENCE]
      ,[JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_PROGRAM_SCHED].[UDF_STEP]
      ,[JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_PROGRAM_SCHED].[UDF_STEP_DURATION]
      ,[JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_PROGRAM_SCHED].[UDF_DAYS_FROM_START]
      ,[JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_INPUT].[UDF_DATE]-[JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_PROGRAM_SCHED].[UDF_DAYS_FROM_START] As "Activity Date"
      ,Step_Atts.[UDF_CYCLEHOURS]
      ,Step_Atts.UDF_ToolCode
      ,sa.UDF_ToolCode
      ,t.UDF_Efficiency AS Efficiency
    
      ,[JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_PROGRAM_SCHED].UDF_LOCATION
      ,[JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_PROGRAM_SCHED].UDF_CYCLE
  FROM 
    Company1.dbo.[JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_INPUT]
          Inner Join Company1.dbo.[JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_PROGRAM_SCHED]
          Inner Join Company1.dbo.[JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_STEP_ATT] AS "Step_Atts"
          Inner Join Company2.dbo.JT_ToolCode
          Inner Join COMPANY1.dbo.JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_STEP_ATT sa
          Inner join Tools t on sa.UDF_TOOLCODE = t.toolcode

  WHERE
    [JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_INPUT].UDF_PROGRAM = [JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_PROGRAM_SCHED].UDF_PROGRAM
        AND [JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_PROGRAM_SCHED].UDF_STEP = Step_Atts.UDF_STEP
        AND Step_Atts.UDF_ToolCode = COMPANY2.dbo.JT_ToolCode.ToolCode
        AND Step_Atts.UDF_PROGRAM = [JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_INPUT].UDF_PROGRAM      
 
  ORDER BY UDF_DATE, UDF_PROGRAM, UDF_SEQUENCE
```

Comment: "It provides me only one response"... well, the code is in a place where only one response is allowed. But also, the `A, B` join syntax has been **obsolete** for **more than 30 years(!)** now, and **should not be used**.

Comment: You seem to be missing a join condition. I don't understand why you do a subquery for a value already available. And using `top` without `order by` is meaningless.

Comment: Why all the subqueries? You seem to be querying the same table multiple times to get the same row.

Comment: @Austin, I unfortunately will not be able to provide a dataset right now. I can try to create something.

Comment: Hi @JoelCoehoorn, thank you for the obsolescence comment, but doesn't help with the question as I am new to SQL (less than a month and half). I am asking for assistance. If you have a better way to do it, I'd like to hear it.

Comment: Then, as someone who is new to SQL, should *learn* to not use syntax that was replaced *32* years ago, @pestomania ; learning the syntax you've used is outdated is helpful. Use *explicit* `JOIN`s.  [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) Honestly, shame on whoever taught you that syntax...

Comment: you have 3 tables but the WHERE is only on two fields. This will mean a cross join. Might wanna fix while you're working on this

Comment: Hi @shawnt00, I have an Order By, I didn't realize be necessary for this question. I can add it. I am still learning on how to join things properly. Can you help explain what you mean by subquery for a value already available?

Comment: @SeanLange, hi I apologies but I don't think I understand your question. I am trying to learn what to do better and am still learning SQL. Do you mind providing an example of your thoughts?

Comment: @ThomA, thank you for providing the link to that document. Makes sense and is very helpful. Joels comment didn't call out how I could change it to be better, rather just stated it was the wrong way to do it. thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Basically you're starting with a join so you have all these rows of data. And then when you do a subquery you're saying, go look up in the original table the tool code that I already have two copies of. I can't tell what you really want to accomplish though.

Comment: Honestly, I suggest tyou take the time to provide some sample data and expected results here. As none of your columns are qualified, it makes it very difficult for us to know what you're trying to achieve, and with no definition of the tables, almost impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your stated question: Presumably the `is null` test is failing, which makes sense. There was already a join performed in that column so looking it up again from the original source will always succeed.The `else` is then executing a non-correlated look-up which means that it will always evaluate to the same answer for every row. (The answer could change depending on how the "first" row cones up.)

It's not clear how the data relates. You appear to want to look in table A first and then table B if not found there. I believe a full join might work.  You'd want to provide some sample data to see if there's a better approach.

```
with Tools as (
    select
        coalesce(t1.ToolCode, t2.ToolCode) as ToolCode,
        coalesce(t1.UDF_EFFICIENCY, t2.UDF_EFFICIENCY) as UDF_EFFICIENCY
    from Company1.dbo.JT_ToolCode t1
         full outer join
         Company2.dbo.JT_ToolCode t2
             on t1.ToolCode = t2.ToolCode
)
select sa.UDF_ToolCode, t.UDF_EFFICIENCY as Efficiency
from Company1.dbo.Step_Atts sa
    inner join Tools t on sa.UDF_ToolCode = t.ToolCode
```

Comment: @SeanLange I have edited the original question with the full query (redacting actual company names) and calling them "Company 1 and Company 2".

Answer (score 1):

Taking the code the OP posted as their solution. This code will use ANSI-92 style joins instead of the antiquated equi-joins. It also uses aliases in an attempt to demonstrate to the OP the advantage of using aliases in making your code more legible.

This should return the same results.

```
SELECT mi.UDF_DATE
      , mi.UDF_QUANTITY
      , mi.UDF_PROGRAM
      , ps.UDF_SEQUENCE
      , ps.UDF_STEP
      , ps.UDF_STEP_DURATION
      , ps.UDF_DAYS_FROM_START
      , mi.UDF_DATE-ps.UDF_DAYS_FROM_START As "Activity Date"
      , sa.UDF_CYCLEHOURS
      , sa.UDF_TOOLCODE
      , t.UDF_EFFICIENCY
      , t.UDF_WCNAME
      , sa.UDF_CYCLEHOURS/t.UDF_EFFICIENCY As "Total Hours"
      , ps.UDF_LOCATION
      , ps.UDF_CYCLE
FROM JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_INPUT mi
join JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_STEP_ATT sa on sa.UDF_PROGRAM = mi.UDF_PROGRAM
join JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_PROGRAM_SCHED ps on mi.UDF_PROGRAM = ps.UDF_PROGRAM and ps.UDF_STEP = sa.UDF_STEP
join #TEMP_TOOL t on sa.UDF_ToolCode = t.ToolCode
```

If you want to go a step further, you really don't need a temp table here. A cte will do the same thing with less overhead.

```
with MyData as
(
    Select *
    FROM Company1.dbo.JT_ToolCode
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * 
    FROM Company2.DBO.JT_ToolCode
)


SELECT mi.UDF_DATE
      , mi.UDF_QUANTITY
      , mi.UDF_PROGRAM
      , ps.UDF_SEQUENCE
      , ps.UDF_STEP
      , ps.UDF_STEP_DURATION
      , ps.UDF_DAYS_FROM_START
      , mi.UDF_DATE-ps.UDF_DAYS_FROM_START As "Activity Date"
      , sa.UDF_CYCLEHOURS
      , sa.UDF_TOOLCODE
      , t.UDF_EFFICIENCY
      , t.UDF_WCNAME
      , sa.UDF_CYCLEHOURS/t.UDF_EFFICIENCY As "Total Hours"
      , ps.UDF_LOCATION
      , ps.UDF_CYCLE
FROM JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_INPUT mi
join JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_STEP_ATT sa on sa.UDF_PROGRAM = mi.UDF_PROGRAM
join JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_PROGRAM_SCHED ps on mi.UDF_PROGRAM = ps.UDF_PROGRAM and ps.UDF_STEP = sa.UDF_STEP
join MyData d on d.UDF_ToolCode = t.ToolCode
```

Answer (score 0):

We figured out a process to create the query and get it to function. Yes, it is still using the `a, b, c` join functionality but that is due to the fact that this is proof of concept and I will clean it up later.

Thank you to all of those that were helpful in their responses and how to fix the problems rather than just informing me I was wrong. I am still learning and a coworker showed me how to create a temp table to accomplish what I need.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    Select * INTO #TEMP_TOOL
    FROM Company1.dbo.JT_ToolCode
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * 
    FROM Company2.DBO.JT_ToolCode
GO

/*SELECT *
FROM #TEMP_TOOL
*/


SELECT [JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_INPUT].[UDF_DATE]
      ,[JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_INPUT].[UDF_QUANTITY]
      ,[JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_INPUT].[UDF_PROGRAM]
      ,[JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_PROGRAM_SCHED].[UDF_SEQUENCE]
      ,[JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_PROGRAM_SCHED].[UDF_STEP]
      ,[JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_PROGRAM_SCHED].[UDF_STEP_DURATION]
      ,[JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_PROGRAM_SCHED].[UDF_DAYS_FROM_START]
      ,[JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_INPUT].[UDF_DATE]-[JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_PROGRAM_SCHED].[UDF_DAYS_FROM_START] As "Activity Date"
      ,[JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_STEP_ATT].[UDF_CYCLEHOURS]
      ,[JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_STEP_ATT].[UDF_TOOLCODE]
      ,#TEMP_TOOL.UDF_EFFICIENCY
      ,#TEMP_TOOL.UDF_WCNAME
      ,[JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_STEP_ATT].[UDF_CYCLEHOURS]/#TEMP_TOOL.UDF_EFFICIENCY As "Total Hours"
      ,[JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_PROGRAM_SCHED].UDF_LOCATION
      ,[JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_PROGRAM_SCHED].UDF_CYCLE
  FROM [JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_INPUT], [JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_PROGRAM_SCHED],[JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_STEP_ATT], #TEMP_TOOL
  Where [JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_INPUT].UDF_PROGRAM = [JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_PROGRAM_SCHED].UDF_PROGRAM
    And [JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_PROGRAM_SCHED].UDF_STEP = [JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_STEP_ATT].UDF_STEP
    AND [JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_STEP_ATT].UDF_ToolCode = #TEMP_TOOL.ToolCode
    AND [JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_STEP_ATT].UDF_PROGRAM = [JT_UDT_CAP_MOD_INPUT].UDF_PROGRAM

GO

ROLLBACK
```